# In django-allauth how and where to set session variables after login?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have successfully integrated allauth and want to set some session variables. Is there any method which is called on login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html

which describes the signals that you can use. You can use `user_logged_in` like this:

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in

def logged_in(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']
    request = kwargs['request']
    request.session['foo'] = 'bar

# Connect django-allauth Signals
user_logged_in.connect(logged_in)
```

if the kwargs are wrong, just add a `print(str(kwargs))` to see what the keys are.